# SQLIte SELECT statement returns same Value in Visual C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, listview, visual-studio-2015

I'm fetching data from my SQLite Database and inserting the list in ListView. But the same data is being repeated in my ListView.

Here's the code to fetch data :

```
public List<Objectdata> getAllData()
    {
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        List<Objectdata> dataList = new List<Objectdata>();
        Objectdata oD = new Objectdata();

        string sql = "select DISTINCT * from data ORDER BY id DESC";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            oD.id = reader["id"].ToString();
            oD.name = reader["name"].ToString();
            oD.address = reader["address"].ToString();
            oD.mobile = reader["mobile"].ToString();
            oD.date = reader["date"].ToString();
            oD.price = reader["price"].ToString();
            oD.warranty = reader["warranty"].ToString();
            oD.month = reader["month"].ToString();

            dataList.Add(oD);

        }

        m_dbConnection.Close();


        return dataList;
    }
```

And this is the code to add data to ListView:

```
 private void button_refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.Items.Clear();
        TableController a = new TableController();
        dataList = a.getAllData();

        listView.ItemsSource = dataList;


    }
```

This is the listview code in xaml:

```
   <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="400" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="645" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="90" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Adrress" Width="130" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding address}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Mobile" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding mobile}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Warranty" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding warranty}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Month" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding month}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The Helper class :

```
  class Objectdata
{


    public String id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String month
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String mobile
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String address
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String date
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String price
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public String warranty
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

This the output:

[image: The Output]

Comment: how dates are stored in the db?

Comment: In Simple date formate MM/DD/YYYY and I calculate the month with inbuilt code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never creating a new `Objectdata` element, but always updating the same one in your loop. Thus all elements in the list are referencing the same object. Add

```
oD = new Objectdata()
```

In your loop after adding you object to the list. Or move your current declaration of `oD` to be the first statement of the loop body. You don't seem to use it outside the loop anyway.

Comment: @basusingh you're welcome. Please don't forget to vote and accept